# upload image but some error in coordinator

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB78S.png)I want to try image upload but image not uplaod some error . i am using coordinator PHP framework
please help me ...

**coordinator insert code here**

```
 public function req()  
        {

         $userID = $this->input->post('userID');
         $fname = $this->input->post('fname');
         $dept_req = $this->input->post('dept_req');
         $except_id = $this->input->post('except_id');
         $message = $this->input->post('message');
         $posted = $this->input->post('posted');

                    $_FILES['photo']['name'];
                    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
                    $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
                    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                    $this->upload->initialize($config);




          $data = [
          'userID' => $userID,
          'fname'=> $fname,
          'dept_req'=> $dept_req,
          'except_id'=> $except_id,
          'message' => $message,
          'photo' => $picture,
          'posted' => $posted
          ];
```

Comment: Hi, please add the error message you are getting

Comment: image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB78S.png

Comment: error here please check image sir

Comment: don't post a picture of something when it's actually text. The error message is important. Please paste the _text_ of the error (**not** pictures, which aren't searchable or copyable) into your question above. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway the error is pretty obvious. You aren't providing a value for the "photo" column in the database, which is required (since NULL values are not allowed). If we look at your code, we can see that's because you wrote `'photo' => $picture`, yet in your PHP code you have never created or populated a variable called $picture until that moment. It's an empty variable. You need to add some data to that variable before you create the query.

Comment: done my error ok thanku